# How to check in SQL which character occurs first in a string

Tags: sql

I have a column with string values which I need to parse based on which of the 2 characters occurred first - @ and /.

Can you please help me with a SQL select query that will check the string? The possible scenarios are:

- Both @ and / are present in the string, if so which one comes first
- Only 1 of the character occurs in the string

Comment: What is your version of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?  We need to know this in order to give an answer here.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far that's not working for you - presumably you've researched and investigated the string functions available in your RDBMS?

Comment: I am using SSMS v18

Comment: For the second scenario, I manage to use case when CHARINDEX ('@', Column) > 0 then //task to do END

Comment: SSMS is your client application not a database - that normally indicates you are using SQL Server. What is your SQL Server version (select @@version)

Comment: MS SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of *charindex* and *outer apply & values*, from which you can select the first-occuring character:

```
select t.*, FirstChar
from t
outer apply(
    select top (1) FirstChar
    from (values
          (CharIndex('@',string),'@'),
          (CharIndex('/',string),'/')
    )v(i,FirstChar)
    where i > 0
    order by i
)x;
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07df5d197ce77cbcd5b1453394dbec58)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in Oracle before I knew it was MS SQL you needed, maybe it can be of some help anyway?

```
with data (text) as(
select '@' from dual union all
select '/' from dual union all
select '@/' from dual union all
select '/@' from dual union all
select '/@/' from dual union all
select '//@' from dual union all
select 'aaa@aaa/aaa' from dual union all
select 'aaa/aaa@aaa' from dual union all
select 'aaaaaaaaa' from dual
)
select text ,
case when INSTR(text,'/')=0 and INSTR(text,'@')>0 then '@' 
     when  INSTR(text,'@')=0 and INSTR(text,'/')>0 then '/' 
     when  INSTR(text,'@')>INSTR(text,'/') then '/' 
     when  INSTR(text,'@')<INSTR(text,'/') then '@'
     else ' '
     end first from data;
```

[image]